# UITextField InputAccessoryView Crashing Application

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitoolbar, uitextinput

I have a simple UIViewController with a few objects in it: A UITextView, and a UIToolBar that gets added as a InputAccessoryView to the UTextView. When viewDidLayoutSubviews is called I set a notification observer to call a function "keyboardDidShow" when the keyboard appears so I can resize the UITextView so it's not behind the keyboard. and when textViewShouldBeginEditing is called I add the InputAccessoryView to the UITextView. But when I go to dismiss the view, a unknown error gets thrown. Also, Once I click on the UITextField in the UIToolBar that acts as the InputAccessoryView, I can no longer go back to edit the UITextView. My code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (!resized) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
        [poemView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    if (!resized) {
        NSDictionary *keyboardInfo = [note userInfo];
        NSValue *keyboardFrameSize = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
        CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameSize CGRectValue];
        toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, toolBar.frame.size.width, toolBar.frame.size.height);

        [txtView setFrame:CGRectMake(txtView.frame.origin.x, txtView.frame.origin.y, txtView.frame.size.width, txtView.frame.size.height - (keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height))];
        [txtView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(txtView.frame.size.width, txtView.frame.size.height - keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height)];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

        resized = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {
    vewTxt = nil;

    [txtView setInputAccessoryView:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (![txtView inputAccessoryView]) {
        [txtView setInputAccessoryView:[self createInputAccessoryView]];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (UIToolbar *)createInputAccessoryView {
    UIToolbar *acc = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [acc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [acc setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [acc sizeToFit];
    [acc setFrame:CGRectMake(0,txtView.frame.size.height - 44, txtView.frame.size.width, 44)];

    vewTxt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, vewTxt.frame.size.width - 25, 25)];
    [vewTxt setText:@"Etc...."];
    [vewTxt setDelegate:self];
    [vewTxt setFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [vewTxt setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [vewTxt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

    UIBarButtonItem *titleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:titleTxt];
        NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:titleItem, nil];
    [acc setItems:items animated:YES];

    return acc;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([[textField text] isEqualToString:@"Etc...."]) {
        [textField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [textField setText:@""];
        [textField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a text view when you create the keyboard accessory view? I am not sure it is wise to have two text views with unclear purposes.

I am sure this is an oversight. Your text view should already exist. Why would you create vewTxt again and again? You can set the frame, but you certainly should not create a new one.

Comment: When I create the keyboard accessory view, I'm making a UIToolBar to use as the keyboard accessory, and adding the vewTxt into the UIToolBar.

Comment: I managed to fixed the crashing, somehow, but I haven't been able to fix that I cannot go back to edit the main UITextView after editing the UITextInput inside the accessory view.